# Accessing multidimension array bug

Tags: php, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

I have a very strange issue with an array converted from an XML object created with SimpleXMLElement. Accessing the same item in 2 fashions gives me two different results.

For example :
$xmlObj['commande']['lignes']
this gives me an array containing an array with 3 items :

```
array(1) {
  ["ligne"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      ["designation"]=>
      string(3) "Don"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(8) {
      ["designation"]=>
      string(15) "Cotisation 2013"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(8) {
      ["designation"]=>
      string(15) "Cotisation 2012"
    }
  }
}
```

and if I print count($orders['ligne']) it gives me 3 which is correct.

but if I use $xmlObj['commande']['lignes']['ligne'] it gives me directly
the first item of the array ligne, as if I had written $xmlObj['commande']['lignes']['ligne'][0]

```
array(8) {
  ["designation"]=>
  string(3) "Don"
}
```

Edited 22h02 : I found the 'problem', when there is one item in an xml list SimpleXML get_object_vars or its Zend equivalent _processXml converts it into an object, otherwise it converts it to an array.

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Comment: Are you sure you have an array, or are are you dealing with a `SimpleXMLElement` object?  How are you trying to access `$xmlObj['commande']['lignes']['ligne']`?  What does `var_dump($xmlObj['commande']['lignes'])` show you?  Is that what you've shown here?

Comment: What does `var_dump($xmlObj)` show you?  You might not actually have an array, but a `SimpleXMLElement` object.

Comment: It shows an array but I converted it using a function I found in Zend, I will try get_object_vars as deem suggested, I did not know about this function!

Answer (score 0):

You use SimpleXMLElement object which implements Traversable/Iterator interface. Convert to a plain array using get_object_vars() to use it you wrote.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, I don't seem to have different results with get_object_vars. Here is the code :

$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement( stripslashes($xmlstr));
$lignes = get_object_vars($xmlArray['lignes']);
$ligneArr = get_object_vars($lignes['ligne']);
echo count($ligneArr); => gives me the number of items in the first array in the item ligne.

I'll put a link to a page that displays some dump.

Comment: Here is the link : view-source:http://www.afsjr.fr/test_xml.php

and the code :
`echo "The XML : \n";
echo $xmlData;

$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement( stripslashes($xmlData));
echo "The SimpleXMLElement : \n";
print_r($xmlObj);

echo "\n\n";

$xmlArray = get_object_vars($xmlObj);
echo "The converted SimpleXMLElement : \n";
print_r($xmlArray);

echo "\n\n";

$lignes = get_object_vars($xmlArray['lignes']);
echo "The converted lignes element : \n";
print_r($lignes);`